# How can i use AND operation in my xpath expression to find total number of authors having pid=1234 in both article and inproceedings folder?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

```
<?php

$xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
$xmlDoc -> load("books.xml");


$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);
$elements = $xpath->evaluate("//dblpperson/r/**article**/author[@pid = '1234']" | "//dblpperson/r/**inproceedings**/author[@pid = '1234']" );

echo count($elements);

?>
```

This is giving an error. Please suggest the correct way to use AND operator.

Comment: Note, there is no AND operation here. Combining two sets into a single set is sometimes called "and" in English (books and magazines) but in logic, set theory, and XPath it is a "union" operation, corresponding to an OR operator (every thing that is either a book OR a magazine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use (you can remove the XPath count () function if you don't want it) :

```
count(//author[@pid="1234"][parent::article or parent::inproceedings])
```

Example with : https://dblp.org/pers/g/Gauthier:Fran=ccedil=ois.xml

```
count(//author[@pid="65/9612"][parent::article or parent::inproceedings])
```

Result : 21